# Leveraging Form Key functions ( save, validate ) on custom Form components

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a series of forms with a number of custom elements ( switches, number selection, datePickers etc..), all of which require the standard validation, onChange and save functions.

I would like to leverage GlobalKey() if possible, specially the validate() and save() functions, however I can't see if this is possible.

Looking at the existing components there is the following which look like they could be leveraged.

```
FormFieldSetter<T>? onSaved,
FormFieldValidator<T>? validator,
```

> Question: Is there a way to leverage formKeys state functions for
> custom form elements?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find an approach and it was as simple as extending out the FormField component.

```
class NumberSelectionFormField extends FormField<int>
```

Then leveraging the OOTB functions

```
  super(
          key: key,
          onSaved: onSaved,
          initialValue: initialValue,
          validator: validator,
          builder: (FormFieldState field) {
```

And ensuring I catered for the error handling from validate in the widget UI

```
          Text(
            field.errorText ?? '',
            style: Styles.errorTextStyle,
          )
```